# Drupal import files

Tags: php, drupal, import, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've been working with Drupal for about a month now and I'm pretty fond of a lot of the things that it does... however, the way it handles files is not something I'm in love with and it is causing me a headache on a media server I'm building for myself.

I have several thousand video files on my local disk (Keep in mind this is a windows machine with drupal installed to C: and the files I want are on D:) that I want Drupal to serve for me.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. I wrote a python script that parses into csv format relevant information from the videos directory my files live in. It outputs a taxonomy file, and a video file (with name/filepath/parent_tag).
2. Imported the taxonomy properly using Feeds.
3. Bashed my head against the wall for a few hours trying to figure out how to get Feeds to digest my videos csv file (name,filepath,parent_tag) to track my videos WITHOUT MOVING THEM FROM THEIR CURRENT DIRECTORY

My simply put question to you is: how can I get Drupal to serve these video files without having it copy all the files to the public:// or private:// directories. I want the files to live on D: while Drupal lives on C:. Currently I have a CSV of all the videos I want to track with the relevant data I want to put into a Video content type.

Thanks!

Comment: Skip feeds importing and write the SQL yourself, perhaps; that's what I ended up doing upgrading from D6 to D7, given the completely new way that it handles media.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can prevent it from moving/copying the file if you're using standard feeds file handling.  But you could probably make a symbolic link in your files directory that points to your D drive.  Then the files will end up on D:.  Under windows use the mklink command to create a link.  You may need to first move your files to a temporary directory so it isn't trying to overwrite each one.